# How to run camera after permission accepted

Tags: java, android

I have fragment that contain method that running camera.
But , when user enter at the first time to the app and going to this fragment, I ask camera permission.
And after user Accept the permission to use camera, camera is not starting.
Only after he is exiting from this fragment and going back to it, the camera will run.

I need some listener for the permission accept i think.

```
surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);

                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `PermissionResult` listener as:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                else
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Permission denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

If you're asking for more than one permission, you can check it as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
    String permission = permissions[i];
    int grantResult = grantResults[i];
    //Now check each permission as
    if (permission.equals(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        //do something like checking granted result
    }
    else if (permission.equals(Manifest.permission.LOCATION)) {
        //do something
    }
}
```